# html table dynamic copy paste causes css auto change on copied table after pasted table css changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple html table which I have to copy and paste dynamically by html copy paste via jquery. On paste, I have just changed the id of the new table.

copied table:

```
<table id=table0>
    <thead>
         <tr><td>head0</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr><td>body0</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

pasted table:

```
<table id=table1>
    <thead>
         <tr><td>head1</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr><td>body1</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have to specify the css rule of that table in the following particular way for my project requirement.

```
#table0 thead tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1){height:25px;width:120px;}
#table0 tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1){height:25px;width:120px;}


#table1 thead tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1){height:25px;width:120px;}
#table1 tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1){height:25px;width:120px;}
```

The 'table1' css is also created dynamically.

Now the problem is, whenever I change the width/height of table1(pasted table), the width/height of table0(copied table) also changes! In my project, there is save option. So, after I save the project and reload the page, then the problem is gone. The problem only occurs when I just paste a table and then change its size.

There is no cache problem or id conflict problem. I have already figured those. May I get some help from any css expert?

Comment: How are you changing the width/height of table1?  JavaScript?  CSS?

Comment: I have a global array named 'CssArr'.Any Table Css Property is stored here on creation.

I change the looking of the tables from this CssArr variable everytime any 'new css' or 'existing css change' is made on that variable.

The storing process on that variable like:
CssArr['#table1 thead tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)']['width'] = '200px';
Finally on project save,CssArr is converted appropriately to store on a css file. And the storing is right,I have already debugged and checked that

When I reload the page after save, the CssArr is filled from the saved css file. Then there is no problem!

Comment: I think to be able to help you, we'll need to see the code for resizing the tables.  It's still a little unclear, even with your comment.